# $\rm Proximinal$ and $\rm \varepsilon-proximinal$ set

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, approximation-theory

When $K$ is a nonempty subset of a metric space $M$, $\forall x \in M$ let 
$P_K(x)=\{y \in K: d(x,y)=d_K(x)=\inf_{k \in K}d(x,k)\}$ (metric projection)

$\bullet$ The set $K$ is $proximinal$ in $M$ if $\forall x \in M$ the set $P_K(x) \neq \emptyset$.

$\bullet$ And The set $K$ is $\varepsilon-proximinal$ in $M$ if $P_K(x)\neq \emptyset$ for each point $x$ of $M$ with $d_K(x)>\varepsilon$.

It's clear every $proximinal$ set is $\varepsilon-proximinal$ set.
I'm looking for a $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}\textbf{$-proximinal$ that is not $proximinal$}$ set ?!

Comment: It is recommended that you provide at least an outline about your own attempt and ideas at solving the problem.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Could you find an example? What makes you think that such an example exists?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for your attention. I thought it would be possible to find such an example among sets that lack some of their cluster points (unclosed).

Comment: @A.Ebadi: indeed, if you allow for nonclosed sets then there are easy examples; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The set $K=[-1, 0)\cup(0, 1]\subset \mathbb R$ is $\epsilon$-proximinal for every $\epsilon>0$ but it is not proximinal, because $P_K(0)=\varnothing$.

It would be harder and more interesting to find examples of a *closed* set that is $\epsilon$-proximinal for every $\epsilon>0$ but not proximinal. I don't know if such an example exists.

**EDIT**. Such an example does not exist for trivial reasons.

**Claim**. If a closed set $K$ is $\epsilon$-proximinal for all $\epsilon>0$, then it is proximinal.

*Proof*. If $x\notin K$, then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\mathrm{dist}(x, K)=\epsilon$ because $K$ is closed. Therefore $P_K(x)\ne \varnothing$. $\Box$

Comment: Exactly, might also be interesting to see [Closed set that is not proximinal
set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449300/closed-set-that-is-not-rm-proximinal-set).

Comment: Do you mean that since K is closed then every point  in its  complement has  a  nearest point in the K? Or I got it wrong? Is the $\epsilon-proximinality$ assumption used?

Comment: Yes, I use the assumption of $\epsilon$-proximinality. If $x\notin K$, then $x$ is in the complement of $K$, which is an open set by definition. Therefore there exists a ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ that contains $x$ and that does not intersect $K$. Since $K$ is $\epsilon$-proximinal, the metric projection $P_K(x)$ is not empty. And since $x$ was arbitrary, we have proven that $P_K(x)\ne \varnothing$ for all $x$. NOTE: This needs that $K$ is $\epsilon$-proximinal for *all* $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: (A side note. If you see an answer that you like, you can *upvote* it, by clicking on the up arrow on the left. If you are satisfied with an answer, you should *accept* it by clicking on the green tick sign. I am not saying that you should upvote and/or accept my answer, I am just informing in case you did not notice. Thank you)

Comment: Anyway: the interesting problem would now be to find a closed set $K$ in a metric space that is $\epsilon$-proximinal *for a fixed value of $\epsilon$*, but is not proximinal. (One can assume $\epsilon=1$). Such example must be infinite-dimensional as closed sets in finite-dimensional normed spaces are all proximinal.

Comment: Given the point you mentioned, yes, you are absolutely right . Thank you very much.

Comment: If we define the $\epsilon-proximinality$ as follows, we can also ask the same question:\\K is $\epsilon−proximinal$ in M if $P_K(x)≠∅$ for each point x of M with $d_K(x)<ε$.