# Condition for which $ \text{dist}(x,A) = d(x,y_0)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> If $(X,d)$ is metric space, $x\in X$ and $A \subset X$. Let's mark $$\text{dist}(x,A) = \text{inf}\; \Big\{ d(x,y) : y \in A \Big\}$$

Does there always exists $y_0 \in A$ that $ \text{dist}(x,A) = d(x,y_0)$ ? Will the answer change, if set $A$ is closed? 
Can someone help to solve this exercise?

Comment: Hint: Try to figure out the answers for $\mathbb R$.

Comment: [Food for thought](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2449276/8157)

Answer (score -1):

**First** Consider a finite dimensional vector space like $\mathbb R$. Take for $x$ the origin.

An example of a bounded subset for which distance is not attained below:

> $A = (1,2]$

If $A$ is compact, then the distance is always attained. For the proof consider a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $d(x_n ,A) \to d(x,A)$ and extract a converging sub-sequence.

If $A$ is closed, then the distance is also always attained. For the proof, consider a point $a \in A$. Then $\overline A = \{y \in A \colon d(x,y) \le d(x,a)\}$ is compact and you can use point above.

**Second.** Case of an infinite dimensional vector space.

In that case, the distance may not be attained even if $A$ is closed. Look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343950/distance-between-a-point-and-closed-set-in-finite-dimensional-space) for a counterexample.